# Loading external image multiple times in Snap.svg: how to cache request?

Tags: snap.svg

I have an image that I'm loading externally, that I'd like to  append multiple times to my svg element.

Currently, if I call `mySnap.load(path)...` each time, it makes an AJAX request for the image. (See jsFiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dvcx3mgt/2/) and watch network tab.) This may or may not be cached by the browser, but I'd like it not to make the requests at all.

I tried to roll my own caching, but it did not work:

```
let cache = {}
let load = function(path, callback) {
  if (cache[path]) {
    callback(cache[path])
  } else {
    Snap.load(path, (img) => {
      cache[path] = img
      callback(img)
    })
  }
}
```

See example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dvcx3mgt/5/)

The issue was that the second time I tried to use the returned value, it had been "emptied out", so to speak. I still had a document-fragment, but it had no contents. I'm assuming that this is because it's pointing at an object that has been manipulated by the Snap library when embedded.

What would be a better way to cache the returned object? The `Fragment` loaded doesn't have a `.clone()` function the way that a `Element` does.

Comment: Append it and then clone it ?

Comment: Or you could possibly store some of the load in a defs statement, and then reference it later with a 'use' element ?

Answer (score 1):

We can simply clone it and append once it has been appended already, or you could possibly reference it as a use element.

```
Snap.load(path, (img) => {
  var el = img.select("g")
  snap.append(el);
  moveIt(el) 
  for( var c=0; c<10; c++) snap.append( moveIt( el.clone() ) )
})

function moveIt( el ) {
  var x = -300 + Math.random() * 120;
  var y = -400 + Math.random() * 120;
  el.transform("t"+x+","+y+" s0.1,0.1");
  return el;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dvcx3mgt/7/)

Comment: Thanks @Ian. However, I was looking for a solution that could be a drop-in replacement for Snap.load, but with caching. That way I could call `load` at any time, without having to be worried about whether I had already called it, and just have the cache work. You solution works, of course, but it just requires me to explicitly handle cloning elements and using them, as opposed to just getting back a (possibly-cached) `Fragment`, like I do with Snap.load. If you have a moment, check out my solution below and see if you see any issues with it.

Comment: Seems fine, not sure there's an obvious issue. Naturally be aware with all the solutions, you may have duplicate IDs from cloning elements is all, but that's the same whatever, and you could probably tidy the transforms etc into a sep func, but that's all superficial really. Other option as mentioned, would be to use a 'use' element like http://jsfiddle.net/dvcx3mgt/14/ to save having to clone and having duplicate IDs and possible amount of stuff in the DOM. I can set that as a possible answer if useful.

Comment: Awesome. A combination of `toDefs` and my cache solution would allow me to call `load` with implicit caching (i.e. not caring about whether I'm getting a cached version or not), while having a smaller DOM. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

While it's true that I could clone the returned element when I use it, and explicitly use a clone the second time, I wanted a "plug-and-play" solution that I wouldn't have to think about: adding a cache to Snap, and being able to load new images at any time without worrying about whether they had already been loaded.

This is the solution I ended up using, once I worked out how to clone the returned document fragment in such a way that I could use it again in the exact same way as I would on a regular load:

```js
// drop-in replacement for Snap.load, with caching
cache = {}
load = function(path, callback) {
  if (cache[path]) {
    callback(Snap(cache[path].node.cloneNode(true)))
  } else {
    Snap.load(path, (img) => {
      cache[path] = Snap(img.node.cloneNode(true))
      callback(img)
    })
  }
}
```

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/5p5wmdc3/

I'll bet that there's a way to add this as an actual plugin, but for the moment I'm happy just calling `MyLib.load` in my path everywhere I used to call `Snap.load`.